# Shell script - can't execute a particular console command on script

Tags: bash, shell

I've a magento 2 installation on my centos 7 server, I need to create a script to execute some particular shell command from the console. 
I've create a simple script that read a file, then It execute all command that I wrote on this file, then It remove the file.

I don't know why, but if execute this script: `HTTP_HOST="<mydomain>" php bin/magento cache:flush` from the console the command is executed with success. If the same command is executed from my script I get this error: `HTTP_HOST="<mydomain>": command not found`

here my script:

```
#! /bin/bash

#imposto il nome del file
filename=command_to_exec.flag
echo ""
echo "-- Sto cercando il file: ${filename}"

#cerco il file
if [ -f $filename ]
then
    #file trovato
    echo "-- File Trovato..."

    #ciclo il file per leggere i comandi
    while read line
        do
        $line
    done < $filename

    #elimino il file
    rm $filename
    echo "File Eliminato"

    #complete!
    echo "-- Procedura Completata"
else
    #file NON trovato
    echo "-- File NON Trovato"
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referring to

```
while read line
    do
    $line
done < $filename
```

The usual approach there would be using **`eval`**

```
while read line
    do
    eval $line
done < $filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it in a different strings like:

```
HTTP_HOST="<mydomain>"
php bin/magento cache:flush
```